# Toggle between end of line and beginning of an inline comment

Tags: text-editing

I'd like to change the default behaviour of pressing <kbd>C-e</kbd> so that, If I have an inline comment, pressing  <kbd>C-e</kbd> should first go to the end of line and pressing it again should go to the beginning of the first non-space character in the inline comment like so :-

`(insert code here) ;; |inline comment.`

How can I achieve this (I know very little elisp to be able to code this :( )? This was inspired by `smarter-move-beginning-of-line` which toggles between the first non-space character in a line and the beginning of line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bumped into this package in MELPA which does exactly what I wanted :- [mwin](https://github.com/alezost/mwim.el)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```lisp
(defun impaktor-move-end-of-line ()
  (interactive)
  (when (comment-search-forward (line-end-position) t)
    (goto-char (match-beginning 0))
    (skip-syntax-backward " " (line-beginning-position))))
```

To this function, you'll probably need to give a shortcut, something like

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f2> e") 'impaktor-move-end-of-line)
```

Courtesy of [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EndOfLineNoComments)

Comment: hmm.. this just moves the cursor to the end of the code before the beginning of the comment. Can I have the behaviour like I described in my post where the cursor would move to the first non white space character in the inline comment?